# scipy linkage (cluster) function equivalient in java/scala

Tags: java, scala

I am looking for a library in java or scala which can do the same clustering like [scipy's linkage](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html) does.

> Performs hierarchical/agglomerative clustering.
>
> The input y may be either a 1d compressed distance matrix or a 2d
>   array of observation vectors.
>
> If y is a 1d compressed distance matrix, then y must be a (n2)(n2)
>   sized vector where n is the number of original observations paired in
>   the distance matrix. The behavior of this function is very similar to
>   the MATLAB linkage function.

The java libraries I have found (like jblas) are pretty low level lacking of higher order algoritms like `linkage`. On the other hand I am pretty sure there are some libraries doing that. Would be nice if you could pin point me to one or two.

PS One can find a lot of indviduals implementing some hierarchical clustering, I prefer something more trustable library like commons math if possible. But there I could only find k means clustering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I am using this library https://github.com/lbehnke/hierarchical-clustering-java

Its not heavyly maintained but passes the comparisment to python and matlab implementations.